# Bulk insert into database by a flutter api laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

I'm trying to make a function in flutter to insert various information into the database but I'm not succeeding because I get an error like this.

**Request function**

```
Future<GeneralRegistersResult<Map<String, dynamic>>> bulkInsert({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String phone,
    required String cpf,
    required int idUser,
    required String token,
  }) async {
    final result = await _httpManager.restRequest(
        url: EndPoints.general_batch,
        method: HttpMethods.post,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
        body: {
          "resources" : [
            {
              "name": name,
              "email": email,
              "phone": phone,
              "cpf": cpf,
              "id_user": idUser
            }
          ]
        },
    );

    if (result['data'] != null) {
      return GeneralRegistersResult<Map<String, dynamic>>.success(result['data']);
    } else {
      return GeneralRegistersResult.error(
        'Não foi possivel carregar os arquivos ${result['message']}',);
    }
  }
```

**insertion**

```
Future<String> pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      dialogTitle: 'Selecione o arquivo',
      allowMultiple: true,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
    );

    if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
      var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
      var formater = String.fromCharCodes(fileBytes!);

      final contacts = formater.split('\r');
      for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length - 1; i++) {
        // Carriage Return ascii code 13
        final contactData = contacts[i].split(';');

        print(RegistersModel(
          name: contactData[0],
          phone: contactData[1],
          email: contactData[2],
          cpf: contactData[3],
        ));

        final GeneralRegistersResult result =
        await generalRegistersRepository.bulkInsert(
          name: contactData[0],
          email: contactData[1],
          phone: contactData[2],
          cpf: contactData[3],
          idUser: 1,
          token: '2|wlWWl4gBRhs9mPvWIRUffddgoLFhjHGZJ8kkPsgK',
        );

        result.when(
          success: (data) {
            print('deu certo de adicionar');
            allRegisters.add(
                RegistersModel(
                  name: contactData[0],
                  phone: contactData[1],
                  email: contactData[2],
                  cpf: contactData[3],
                ),
            );
          },
          error: (message) {
            utilsServices.showToast(
              message: message,
              isError: true,
            );
          },
        );
      }

      return csv = formater;
    } else {
      return 'O documento não foi retornado';
    }
  }
```

This is in flutter, the error that appears is:

Não foi possivel carregar os arquivos SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 7 ERROR: value too long for type character varying(15) (SQL:insert into "general_registers" ("name", "email", "phone", "cpf", "id_user", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Pablo, (16)98754-6548, pablo.teste@gmail.com, 154.368.954-80, 1, 2022-11-17 11:56:07, 2022-11-17 11:56:17) returning "id")

***Could you help me, because since I'm new to programming, I don't know how to solve this.***

**This is the model I have to make from Json**

```
{
    "resources" : [
            {
            "name": "Massa1",
            "email": "teste@gmail.com",
            "phone": "(16) 96487-3218",
            "cpf": "868.242.440-15",
            "id_user": 1
            },
            {
            "name": "Massa2",
            "email": "teste@gmail.com",
            "phone": "(16) 96487-3218",
            "cpf": "868.242.440-15",
            "id_user": 1
            },
            {
            "name": "Massa3",
            "email": "teste@gmail.com",
            "phone": "(16) 96487-3218",
            "cpf": "868.242.440-15",
            "id_user": 1
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: So it says that the value is too long for a column which is Varying(15). The only data I see longer than 15 characters is the email you are trying to insert. Is your email column in the database 15 characters? Perhaps you should increase the column size?

Comment: My email column te 60:
email character varying(60) NOT NULL,

Comment: Reducing the amount of characters in the email and it almost worked, because it gave an error later and did not clean everything

Comment: I was able to find the error, the field where the email and telephone information is stored were changed, because of that the error was generated, thank you very much for helping me to see this!